# R how to apply select variable from one data frame to apply in an row-wise equation on another data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames of different dimensions, one containing observations and the other containing constants that are related to the observations for use arithmetically.  What I wish to do is to select the appropriate constant from df2 to use with the row-wise observations in df1 to produce df3.

I've attached sample data and a simple equation:

```
# df1 with annual observation data from different commodities

df1 <- data.frame(Region = c("Europe", "Asia", "N.Amer", "Africa"), 
                  Item = c("Wheat", "Barley", "Oats", "Rice"), 
                  Year = c(1961, 1961, 1961, 1961), 
                  Production = c(2000, 1000, 1500, 500), 
                  Imports = c(1000, 200, 3000, 100), 
                  Stock.Var = c(-100, 300, 50, 0), 
                  Exports = c(250, 150, 100, 200))

#df2 with constants for losses by commodity in different regions

df2 <- data.frame(Area = c("Asia", "N.Amer", "Europe", "Africa"),
                  Item = c("Wheat", "Oats", "Rice", "Barley"), 
                  LF1 = c(0.02, 0.1, 0.15, 0.05))

# df3 would contain the outputs from calculating losses from df1 by df2 by  row
# Equation: L1 = (Production + Imports + Stock.Var - Exports) * LF1
```

The value for LF1 in the equation is taken from df2 based upon the Item & Region name in df1.

The full size of df1 is several hundred thousand rows by 16 columns; df2 is about 150 rows by 20 columns.

Comment: Of the Area+Item combinations in `df2`, only one of them (N.Amer+Oats) matches up to the Region+Item combinations present in `df1`. Is this intentional, or because the examples show only a part of each data frame?

Comment: Just `merge()` the data.frames together to get the correct coefficient for each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)'s `inner_join` and `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = c(Region = "Area", "Item")) %>%
    mutate(L1 = (Production + Imports + Stock.Var - Exports) * LF1)
```

If you'd rather stick to base R, you could use `merge`:

```
m <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("Region", "Item"), by.y = c("Area", "Item"))
m$L1 <- (m$Production + m$Imports + m$Stock.Var - m$Exports) * m$LF1
```

Comment: Many thanks, David.  One line of code... I obviously have a lot to learn (I had expected to need some sort of looping function)!